# Amazon ELB session stickiness across TCP 443 connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tcp, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

In the deployment scenario I am using, there is a single ELB, balancing multiple EC2 instances, serving a multi-domain system. Since ELB doesn't support multiple SSL certificates on HTTPS, ELB port 443 is configured as TCP 443, which points to port 9443 on EC2 instances (with Proxy Protocol enabled).

This way installing multiple SSL certificates using a single ELB is possible, as described in [this blog post](http://garthkerr.com/multiple-ssl-domains-on-elb-with-nginx/).

The problem now is that stickiness policy cannot be associated only with a listener with HTTPS as frontend protocol.

However, I cannot use HTTPS as frontend protocol, because of the multiple domains/SSL certificates point made above.

What would be the best way to handle the issue?

Comment: Could you use separate ELBs, one for each separate domain/certificate, which all balance to the same set of backend instances?

Comment: Yes, but the domains are about 30, so I thought it might be hard to maintain,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested by @Castaglia, I ended up with configuration of separate ELBs, one for each domain/certificate pair.

In the auto scaling configuration, you have option to specify multiple ELBs.